# Items maximum quantity or price do not allow checkout magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, error

Not able to checkout.
Please find attachment and suggest any solution.
[image]

Comment: Have you check your system configuration?

Comment: @Dhiren, What I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify this things,

1. Please open admin panel, navigate to System menu ->Configuration.
2. Click "Inventory" button in the Catalog section on the left and then "Product Stock Options".
3. You may set "Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart"

You can also check this link : http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/price-cant-be-greater-than-100000000-41902.html

Comment: I have only a single item  in cart, but the amt is that is displayed in attachment

Comment: Can you try with diffrent item in cart with single qty?

Comment: Check above link, you get idea. I update my answer.

Comment: @Yogita have you check, did you find your solution.